# Groovy passing string value inside the xpath with single quote - Katalon

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, groovy, katalon-studio

I have created a custom keyword function in Katalon Studio using Groovy.

Below is my function

```
def referenceTabRecordSelection(String expectedRefState,String tableid){
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
        WebElement RefTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id= '+tableid+' ]/tbody'))
}
```

"tableid" string is passed inside the XPath.

While executing I'm getting `NoSuchElementException`

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=usRef]/tbody"}
```

After investigation, id value in the xpath is not populated with a single quote like

`[@id='usRef']`/tbody

Let me know how can I pass the string variable value inside the XPath with a single quote.

Comment: `By.xpath('//*[@id= \''+tableid+'\' ]/tbody')`

Comment: Why would it?  You have to add this quotes inside the string.  E.g.: `By.xpath("//*[@id= '$tableid']/tbody")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Groovy's string interpolation:

```
def referenceTabRecordSelection(String expectedRefState,String tableid){
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement RefTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableid}']/tbody"))
}
```

Note you need to start the interpolated string with double quotes for the string interpolation to work.

Comment: Thanks but i'm getting below script error Groovy:unexpected token: $ @ line 94, column 63.

Comment: You are missing the closing curly bracket "}" in the original post. Check your code if you have the closures right.

Comment: yes its added but getting the same error WebElement RefTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id='${tableid}']/tbody'))

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to start with the double quotes: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableid}']/tbody"))`